# gcc command line structure arguments

Tags: gcc-warning

I try to compile a c file with gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1).
I run the compiler in the source file's folder, but I keep getting the 'file not found' error message for the last argument ('*bcm2835*').

```
   gcc -o gpio -l rt /home/pi/bcm2835-1.15/src/bcm2835.c -l bcm2835
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbcm2835
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

AFAIK, The gcc does not specify the third argument, I have no idea what this 3rd argument is used for and where to find it.
If I omit that argument, I get several error lines, each for one of the internal commands, like:

`undefined reference to bcm2835_init`

I also wish to know what the ***rt*** stands for. I could not find it in the official gcc docs.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After `-l`, there should be no space. So it should be `-lrt` (not `-l rt`) and it should be `-lbcm2835` (not `-l bcm2835`).

You need to add a linker search path with `-L` (uppercase L) right before calling `-lbcm2835`.

The input file should usually be last (that's the argument ending with `main.c`). That would be

```
gcc -o main -lrt -lbcm2835 /home/pi/bcm2835-1.15/main.c
```

`-l` links a library to the program. `-L` sets the library search path such that `-l` will find the libraries specified.

See [this page](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html) for details on `-l` and `-L`.

Comment: Sorry, Michael, I edited the thread while you were sending your reply, so there is new text.
In any case, I tried your suggestions but I still get the same,
gcc -o main -lrt -lbcm2835 /home/pi/bcm2835-1.15/src/bcm2835.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbcm2835. 
Where shall I look for the linker and where shall I place the -L?

Comment: @samtal: You need to understand what `-l` and `-L` is actually supposed to do. And what a library search path is. You cannot just put `-L` somewhere, because it is not a magic "please work"-switch. `-L` is supposed to tell the compiler where to find the `bcm2835.a` library.

Comment: Thanks, Michael,
It seems now as if the whole problem is due to improper permissions on my computer. In any case, I'v learned something new, as I always do, even if minor...
I'm in the process of cleaning up the permissions after which I will give it another try with the hope it will work.
I'll then update this thread.

Comment: To finalize and close this issue, yes, the gcc compiling problem was the result of improper files and folder ownership.
To make compiling work, the user must have access to the libraries or libs be owned by the user or else 'file not find' errors will show up.